# Change Django setting ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py only when running pytest

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I've got a test that I'm trying to run where I login to my django application:

```
class FirefoxTestCases(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        data_setup.basic_apps_setup(self)
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_log_in_with_no_apps_displays_firefox(self):
        # Opening the link we want to test
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
        assert "log in" in self.browser.page_source
        time.sleep(2)
        self.browser.find_element_by_id("id_username").send_keys("userone")
        self.browser.find_element_by_id("id_password").send_keys("test")
        self.browser.find_element_by_id("log_in").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        # Check the returned result
        assert "Something appears to be missing" in self.browser.page_source
```

In doing this - it doesn't actually allow the login because in my settings I have specific `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setup.

Is there a way to access the ALLOWED_HOSTS settings when running this test so that it will allow login when testing?

Comment: It should be taken care of.. check the middle of `setupClass(..): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/test/testcases/#LiveServerTestCase

Comment: You're right. Turns out it was the `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` that was getting set in the settings. Since testing is only using `localhost` there is no domain attached to it... by doing `@override_settings(SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN="")` it works and behaves in an expected way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in `settings.py` the `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` was being set.

For example:

`SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".company.com"`

Django LiveServerTestCase only does `localhost` (and as far as I can tell is unchangeable). So because of this the logged in users cookie wasn't being recognized by the site at `localhost`

In order to fix this - for tests requiring interactivity (such as logging in) you can [override that setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/) like this:

```
from django.test.utils import override_settings
...

...
@override_settings(SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN="")
def test_log_in_with_no_apps_displays_firefox(self):
    # Opening the link we want to test
    self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
    assert "log in" in self.browser.page_source
    time.sleep(2)
    self.browser.find_element_by_id("id_username").send_keys("userone")
    self.browser.find_element_by_id("id_password").send_keys("test")
    self.browser.find_element_by_id("log_in").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    # Check the returned result
    assert "Something appears to be missing" in self.browser.page_source
```

This test will override that setting and the user will be able to successfully login without issue.

Any additional functionality the site would usually have that was unavailable because of cookie issues is now resolved.